# VSS 6.0 with VS2012

Tags: c#, .net, version-control, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli

The company I work in and that **I don't have any control over its source control software** uses `vss 6.0`
up to`vs2010`vs recognized `vss6.0` and all I needed to do is register `SSSCC.DLL` and the plugin appeared in the Tools->sourcecontrol->plugin selection

that doesn't seem to work in `vs2012 express` , perhaps someone knows a workaround?

suggesting me to migrate to other source control just won't help, though if theres a new source control ***client*** with a vs plugin that can connect to `vss 6.0 sp6 server` it would help.

Comment: Do you use VS2012 express?

Comment: yes. for now. (it does have TFS sopport)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VS2012 Express` doesn't support `VSS`: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssourcecontrol/thread/76ed94be-b81d-4ad1-968f-dcdfd6c108df

Comment: Is this really a valid answer? I would recommend putting this as a comment.

Comment: 2010 doesn't support cli intelisense don't have money for 2012. F**************

Comment: @UweKeim: If the question is "How can I ...?" shouldn't "You can not" be a valid answer (if it's correct)?

Comment: @igrimpe Sorry, I just read the only question as "perhaps someone knows a workaround?", so I guessed that a workaround would be a valid answer. Probably I got this wrong.

Comment: @UweKeim That piece was added do the question after this answer was posted